# spark structured streaming unable to start from checkpoint location

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm doing a simple Spark program using structured streaming feature and Kafka. As Kafka is source, there are 2 sinks:

- Sink 1- Console sink -- works fine in all cases
- Sink 2 & 3 -H2 and Ignite Foreach sink

For the first run code runs fine but when I kill and restart the program with checkpoint location I'm getting the below error

```
17/07/12 07:11:48 ERROR StreamExecution: Query h2Out [id = 22ce7168-6f12-4220-8f28-f9eaaaba9c6a, runId = 39ecb40a-5b54-4b36-a0da-6e3057d66b2e] terminated with error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anon$1.parseVersion(Ljava/lang/String;I)I
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anon$1.deserialize(KafkaSource.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource$$anon$1.deserialize(KafkaSource.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.get(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.initialPartitionOffsets$lzycompute(KafkaSource.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.initialPartitionOffsets(KafkaSource.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.getBatch(KafkaSource.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(StreamExecution.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(StreamExecution.scala:448)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.foreach(StreamProgress.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamProgress.flatMap(StreamProgress.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2.apply(StreamExecution.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$2.apply(StreamExecution.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:177)
```

I checked `KafkaSource` source code, the parseFunction method is available through `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog` I hope, for which the jar (`spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar`) is available in classpath. 
For info I'm using Kafka 0.10.2.1 maven dependencies.

Comment: What are the application's dependencies? How do you build the app? How do you run it?

Answer (score 3):

This error means your Spark version is older than 2.1.1. `HDFSMetadataLog.parseVersion` adds in Spark 2.1.1, and `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.1.jar` calls it. If your Spark version is older than 2.1.1, you will see this NoSuchMethodError.

You can check your Spark version by calling `SparkSession.version`. (e.g., just type `spark.version` in Spark shell).